# Can't access an FXML control

Tags: java, javafx

When I have a controller that accesses the controls of the FXML through `@FXML`, then I don't neeed to initialize them. I can just access them (`result.setText("test")` for example), as I can see in various examples. For some reason, that doesn't work for me and I can't find the reason. Can someone tell me the reason please?

```
public class WiderstandController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField input;

    @FXML
    private Label result;

    @FXML
    private Button btn;

    @FXML
    private void berechne() {
        result.setText("test");
        System.out.println(result.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    }

}
```

And here is the relevant FXML part (inside a `Pane`):

```
fx:controller="widerstand.WiderstandController"
```

Can you see what is wrong or do you need more? I don't want to spam everything here if we can find it already in that class.

EDIT: by not being able to access I mean that I get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Did you set `fx:id` attributes in your FXML?

Comment: Well, obviously you're getting a `NullPointerException` in method `berechne()` because `result` is null.  The FXML Loader has not found a control to inject into your `result` variable.  Can you show us the stack trace for your error, as well as the FXML for your controls?  You've not given us enough information to say where the problem is.

Comment: @sillyfly This was the problem. That was hard to figure out tbh. Thanks.

Comment: @sillyfly why don't you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake I made was not changing `id` to `fx:id` in the FXML file.